# R: creating a pdf in a function does not work

Tags: pdf-generation, quantmod

When pdf() is in a function it does not appear to generate the pdf.
What is the fix?

**h.r**

```
# R --silent --vanilla < h.r
library(quantmod)

gs <-function(f) {
  csv <- read.csv(text="s,n\nF,Ford\nV,Visa", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
  symVec <- getSymbols(as.vector(csv$s))
  infoVec <- mapply(paste, csv$s, csv$n, sep=": ") # eg. "F: Ford"
  pdf("a.pdf")
  par(mfrow=c(5,7))
  mapply (chart_Series, mget(symVec), name=infoVec)
  dev.off()
}

main <- function() {
  # get symbols, create pdf
  gs(f)
}

if(!interactive()) {
  main()
}
```

**output**

```
null device 
          1 
>
```

Answer (score 0):

To generate a pdf inside a function you have to use “print”. In your function `gs` enclose the “mapply” line with `print` like so:

```
print(mapply (chart_Series, mget(symVec), name=infoVec))
```